# AppleScript VLC Scripting Bridge

Tags: objective-c, macos, header-files, vlc, scripting-bridge

I am trying to use the [Scripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html) to control VLC. However, I seem unable to access all methods. I generated the file using:

```
sdef /Applications/VLC.app | sdp -fh --basename VLC
```

I can access properties such as `vlc.pathOfCurrentItem` just fine. Even this notation works: `[vlc pathOfCurrentItem];`.

However, all methods seem to be grouped into a `VLCGenericMethods` protocol and seperate from the `VLCApplication` interface. `[vlc stop]` throws a compile-time error of: `No visible @interface for 'VLCApplication' declares the selector 'stop'`.

What am I doing wrong? My code is literally:

```
VLCApplication *vlc = (VLCApplication *)[self.application sbApplication];
[vlc stop];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripting Bridge is buggy, crippled, and very prone to application conflicts. You may want to consider using AppleScript instead - the language may be crap, but it's the only supported option that knows how to speak Apple events right. The AppleScript-ObjC bridge takes most of the pain out of bridging between the two languages: [here's a quick how-to](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html).

Comment: This would work, but I would prefer to use the scripting bridge. If nobody else answers for a while, I will mark this as accepted.